# binary search tree of 20 elements

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So this code for creating searching and removing nodes to a BST works great but only if it is of size nine how do i make it be of size 20  when i change the SIZE to 20 the programs does not go past the first print statement where it say binary tree sorry for the long code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define SIZE 9

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} node;
 typedef int (*comparer)(int, int);
typedef void (*callback)(node*);


/*create a new node*/
node* create_node(int data)
{
    node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Out of memory!!! (create_node)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

/*remove all nodes of the tree*/
void dispose(node* root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        dispose(root->left);
        dispose(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

/*search*/
node* search(node *root,const int data,comparer compare)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int r;
    node* cursor = root;
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        r = compare(data,cursor->data);
        if(r < 0)
            cursor = cursor->left;
        else if(r > 0)
            cursor = cursor->right;
        else
            return cursor;
    }
    return cursor;

}

/*delete a node*/
node* delete_node(node* root, int data,comparer compare)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node *cursor;
    int r = compare(data,root->data);
    if( r < 0)
        root->left = delete_node( root->left, data,compare);
    else if( r > 0 )
        root->right = delete_node(root->right,data,compare);
    else
    {
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            cursor = root->right;
            free(root);
            root = cursor;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            cursor = root->left;
            free(root);
            root = cursor;
        }
        else 
        {
            cursor = root->right;
            node *parent = NULL;

            while(cursor->left != NULL)
            {
                parent = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->left;
            }
            root->data = cursor->data;
            if (parent != NULL)
                parent->left = delete_node(parent->left, parent->left->data,compare);
            else
                root->right = delete_node(root->right, root->right->data,compare);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

/*insert a new node*/
node* insert_node(node *root, comparer compare, int data)
{

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = create_node(data);
    }
    else
    {
        int is_left  = 0;
        int r        = 0;
        node* cursor = root;
        node* prev   = NULL;

        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            r = compare(data,cursor->data);
            prev = cursor;
            if(r < 0)
            {
                is_left = 1;
                cursor = cursor->left;
            }
            else if(r > 0)
            {
                is_left = 0;
                cursor = cursor->right;
            }

        }
        if(is_left)
            prev->left = create_node(data);
        else
            prev->right = create_node(data);

    }
    return root;
}

/* compare two integers*/

int compare(int left,int right)
{
    if(left > right)
        return 1;
    if(left < right)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

/*display a node's key*/

void display(node* nd)
{
    if(nd != NULL)
        printf("%d ",nd->data);
}

/*display tree or subtree*/

void display_tree(node* nd)
{
    if (nd == NULL)
        return;
    /* display node data */

    printf("%d",nd->data);
    if(nd->left != NULL)
        printf("(L:%d)",nd->left->data);
    if(nd->right != NULL)
        printf("(R:%d)",nd->right->data);
    printf("\n");

    display_tree(nd->left);
    display_tree(nd->right);
}


int main()
{
    node* root = NULL;
    comparer int_comp = compare;
    callback f = display;

    /* insert data into the tree */
    int a[SIZE];
    int i,b;

/* This takes the input from the user for the tree*/
    printf("\nPlease input the 20 numbers you want to summit to the TREE\n");
        for (b =0; b < SIZE; b++)
        {
        printf("#%2d > ", b+1);
        scanf("%d", &a[b]);
        }

    printf("--- C Binary Search Tree ---- \n\n");
    printf("Insert: ");
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
        root = insert_node(root,int_comp,a[i]);
    }
    printf(" into the tree.\n\n");

    /* display the tree */
    display_tree(root);

    /* remove element */
    int r;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter data to remove, (-1 to exit):");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        if(r == -1)
            break;
        root = delete_node(root,r,int_comp);
        /* display the tree */
        if(root != NULL)
            display_tree(root);
        else
            break;
    }
    while(root != NULL);

    /* search for a node */
    int key = 0;
    node *s;
    while(key != -1)
    {
        printf("Enter data to search (-1 to exit):");
        scanf("%d",&key);

        s = search(root,key,int_comp);
        if(s != NULL)
        {
            printf("Found it %d",s->data);
            if(s->left != NULL)
                printf("(L: %d)",s->left->data);
            if(s->right != NULL)
                printf("(R: %d)",s->right->data);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("node %d not found\n",key);
        }
    }

    /* remove the whole tree */
    dispose(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I just ran your code. It seems to take a long time to insert. Why don't you insert the numbers into the tree as the user inputs numbers. This speeded up the code tremendously.

Comment: i am very new at this and did not know how to

Comment: that is also how the teacher taught it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store the input in an array. In the part of the code where you read input from the user, just insert the number into the array. I'm not too familiar with C, but do something like:

```
int i;  
for (b =0; b < SIZE; b++)
  {
    printf("#%2d > ", b+1);
    scanf("%d", &i);
    root = insert_node(root, int_comp, i); 
  }
```

It is working correctly in your case, but if you change the size to 20, it goes very slowly, which is why you think it does not work. Doing it in this manner will speed up the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, tried to change the SIZE to 20, and it is working correctly in both cases. Maybe you have changed something else? Moreover, as OGH said, why do you store the input in an array first, consuming more time and limiting the maximum size of the input?

Comment: see i dont understand when i change it it does not go past the binary tree print statement